# Dropzone is not working on server. Working fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I would like to upload images by using dropzone. It is working fine on localhost. I am able to upload files. But when I uploaded my code server it is not initializing. I am triggering event on click of button.

My code -

```
//other fields

<div class="dropzone" id="addProductDropzoneNew"></div>

//other fields
```

Js -

```
Dropzone.options.addProductDropzoneNew= {
  url: '/admin/product/store',
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 5,
  maxFiles: 5,
  maxFilesize: 1,
  acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.PNG',
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {
      dzClosure = this;
      document.getElementById("new-product-btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          if (dzClosure.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
            var blob = new Blob();
            blob.upload = { 'chunked': dzClosure.defaultOptions.chunking };
            dzClosure.uploadFile(blob);
          } else {
            dzClosure.processQueue();
          }
      });
      this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
          formData.append("_token", jQuery("#token").val());
          formData.append("id", jQuery("#productId").val());
          formData.append("name", jQuery("#name").val());
          formData.append("sku", jQuery("#sku").val());
          formData.append("menuId", jQuery("#menuId").val());
          formData.append("categoryId", jQuery("#category").val());
          formData.append("subCategory", jQuery("#sub").val());
          formData.append("price", jQuery("#price").val());
          formData.append("discount", jQuery("#discount").val());
          formData.append("stock", jQuery("#stock").val());
          formData.append("color", jQuery("#color").val());
          formData.append("size", jQuery("#size").val());
          formData.append("height", jQuery("#height").val());
          formData.append("width", jQuery("#width").val());
          formData.append("weight", jQuery("#weight").val());
          formData.append("description", jQuery("#description").val());
          formData.append("isPublish", jQuery("#isPublish").val());
          formData.append("isB2B", jQuery("#isB2B").val());
          formData.append("title", jQuery("#title").val());
          formData.append("keyword", jQuery("#keyword").val());
          formData.append("metaDescription", jQuery("#metaDescription").val());
          formData.append("brandId", jQuery("#brandId").val());
          formData.append("isFreeShipping", jQuery("#shipping").val());
      });
  },
  success: function(data) 
  {
    clearError();
    if(data.status=='success'){
        location.href='/admin/product';
    } else {
        displayError(data.xhr.response);
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure but it is working fine on local. But i guess it is not initializing on server.

Here is screenshot of local - [image]

This is a screenshot of dropzone div on server - [image]

Also, in developer console log not getting any error. Please check image - [image]

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What does the browser's Developer Console tell?

Comment: Nothing. There is no any error.

Comment: Please check console log image. Question edited.

Comment: Check requests in dev tools network. Not much here in the way of debugging details. Check server logs also

Comment: Can you reload the page and check the network tab to make sure the script is loading?

Comment: Yes. Script is there. Also, cleared cache many times. And tried with restarting apache.

Comment: If are certain that your code is up to date in the production server. I suggest restarting your server. If that helps then I would look into any caching on the serverside like OP cache  or framework level caching.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Restart server and tried. But no change. Also, tried to clear server cache. But no use.

Comment: @AbhishekHonrao have u checked `network tab`.? what response u r getting and what payload sent

Comment: @KamleshPaul I am unable to click and upload images on that particular div. So I can't check payload.

Comment: @AbhishekHonrao  `new Dropzone("#addProductDropzoneNew", { url: "/file/post"});` run this in your browser console and check it is `init` if not then u need to fix javascript library

Comment: @KamleshPaul. Thank you for this suggestion. It is working if use this command. It is initializing dropzone. Can you please let me know solution?

Comment: @AbhishekHonrao oh then problem with your javascript order u need  to put `your` code after all is loaded

Comment: @KamleshPaul. Ok trying.

Comment: @KamleshPaul. No luck. Still same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221126/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-abhishek-honrao).